# SDLWEB8 : Maximum field length item name(Schema Name, Component Name)

Tags: translation-manager, web8.5

What is Maximum length of Schema Name, Component Name, Page Name, Structure Group Name and Bundle Name? I want check with TMS translation support this length or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 255 characters (out of the top of my head) but the constraint is configurable in `cm_xml_usr.xsd`.

There is a hard limit in the database: 255 characters for MSSQL and (IIRC) 510 UTF-8 encoded bytes for Oracle. The latter is a rather fuzzy limit, because it depends on which characters you are using: a character uses between 1 and 3 bytes when UTF-8 encoded.